# Does Detect Magic make an Arcane Mark placed on an invisible surface glow?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, invisibility

Invisible arcane marks glow when hit by Detect Magic.

Usually, how this works is that someone casts Detect Magic on an item and they see this fluorescent drawing on it, marking it as the belonging of some specific mage.

This time, however, we have a creature that likes turning invisible every time it hears our magus cast True Strike or every time too many people swarm them, and the magus would like to slap an arcane mark on their back so that, when the creature goes invisible, a round 1 Detect Magic causes the glow, marking the square and letting everyone but the Detect Magic caster target the right square.

Does this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Signs point to "yes" with some wiggle room for GM interpretation.

The first hurdle: can [Arcane Mark](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/arcane-mark/) be cast on a creature?

> If an arcane mark is placed on a living being, ...

So, yes.

The second hurdle: can it be cast on an unwilling creature?

> Range: touch

... and, there's no "Target" field, so the spell doesn't specify that it *can't* be cast on an unwilling creature (though, a touch attack is likely required to do so).

The third hurdle: does it matter how the Mark is made invisible?

An Arcane Mark itself "can be visible or invisible", and "[i]f an invisible mark is made, a detect magic spell causes it to glow and be visible". So, an Arcane Mark which is created as an invisible Mark is definitely revealed by [Detect Magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-magic/). But, what about a mark which is made on something which is later affected by [Invisibility](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility/) (or its variants)?

Fortunately, Invisibility answers that question:

> Light, however, never becomes invisible, although a source of light can become so (thus, the effect is that of a light with no visible source).

Since the Arcane Mark explicitly glows, it's a light source; since it's a light source, the mark itself is visible-ish (at the very least, the square it's in should be readily detectible, in the general case).

So, where does GM interpretation come in?

First: since Arcane Mark doesn't explicitly state that it can be cast on an unwilling target, the GM could rule that it can't be. This is something that the GM should be freely willing to talk about before the tactic is tried, of course.

Second: if the Mark is somewhere that the target can cover it (with a cloak or something), the GM could rule that the target can cover the mark, hiding the light (this GM remembers this being a valid option, but can't find rules support at the moment; also, in fairness, this rule should apply to light sources generally: players should be able to close an invisible bullseye lantern or hide an everburning torch in their cloak to prevent foes from seeing the light source at the cost of not having it available themselves).

Third: the GM could rule that the area is bright enough that determining which square the target is in requires a perception check (simulationist real-world example: telling if a non-OLED LCD/LED display is on by seeing the ... "brighter shade of black", I guess ... in a bright room vs. a dark room).

For what it's worth, this GM thinks the tactic is clever. Further, since there's a real cost to using it (it burns an action, which is the most valuable currency in the game), I wouldn't be prone to nerfing it via either of the "interpretation" options above. However, I would have some canny foes who have had time and reason to watch the PCs in action (or to have received reports) use the tactic against them or be otherwise prepared for it (eg., by preparing - and preparing for - [Darkness](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/darkness/)).

Comment: I don't think you can hide a light source inside an invisible object to conceal the light.  Invisible things must become completely transparent; they can't be "visually undetectable" (the definition of the condition) if they block line of sight. Say you're looking down a long corridor with an obstruction partway (say a giant statue).  If casting 'invisibility' on the statue means it blocks line of sight, it will be VERY obvious. It seems to me 'invisible' must really mean 'transparent', thus a light source is easily visible even when surrounded by transparent/invisible material.

Comment: Hiding a light source under an invisible cloak (or in an invisible pocket/bag/...) may not make sense from a "real world physics" perspective, but neither does invisibility generally. From a game perspective, it makes a lot of sense: the rogue can carry an everburning torch in their backpack or an [Ioun Torch](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-torch/) in their pocket to help pick locks and such while still sneaking invisibly down a hall to scout.

Comment: Ah, right. I was trying to figure out the difference between an originally invisible Arcane Mark and one placed on an invisible surface, but one can just place the invisible mark on the surface and when it turns invisible, nothing changes.

Comment: I'm not talking about a "real world physics" perspective of how the _magic spell_ works ("not at all" being the answer to that question;).  I'm talking about the need for its effects to be consistent and easy to apply, so it doesn't slow the game down.  And how the only mention of special rules for light sources is that the light still exists, and it specifically says the effect is light with no apparent source.  To me that answers the question unambiguously.

Comment: @TonDay: fair enough. All I can say is that I'd swear I read that covering an invisible light source with something made invisible (possibly "by the same effect") would hide the light. Similarly, that an invisible bullseye lantern would continue to focus the light it throws. I can't find rule support so RAW likely leans in your direction on this one, but every table I've played at has let light sources be hidden on invisible creatures so long as the creature doesn't benefit from the light (magic lights that only work for the bearer notwithstanding).